# Can i convert SCORM content into html5 format?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2, tin-can-api

I created the SCORM OF swf content. so how can I convert this SCORM into another SCORM having same content but in HTML5 format?? Is there any direct or Indirect way??

Comment: Is your question really related to programming? In general: No, you cannot convert Flash to HTML 5. SCORM is just a wrapper, it is a zip file you can edit. Thus, SCORM is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes and no.

I am guessing you are using a tool like captivate or articulate to design your courses. The newest Captivate and Articulate content creation tools will output the content in Flash and HTML5.

see: https://vimeo.com/65419715
and here: http://www.articulate.com/support/storyline/viewing-and-tracking-articulate-storyline-content-in-an-lms

I haven't heard of any conversion tools and I think that word throws people off.

SCORM is not tied to Flash but instead more connected to javascript. 

This is a related question: [Looking for SCORM compliant course example in pure HTML with mp3 without flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428165/looking-for-scorm-compliant-course-example-in-pure-html-with-mp3-without-flash/27432291#27432291)

So if you can write javascript, you could also re-create your courses in HTML5.

edit:
There aren't any specific tools for SCORMED FLASH to HTML5 that I know of for the content development industry. There are some tools that would convert FLASH to HTML5 and javascript.   You could try this tool:

http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/

This should work so long as your flash course is not password locked.

Comment: Thanks joel..., I will try to do this. but don't you think there is scope to create such a tool which will convert SCORM of flash content into SCORM of HTML5 content..???

Comment: Actually, i  m not working on course designing. i have some redimate SCORM of flash content and i want to convert that scorm content into HTML 5 format.

Comment: I've made an update to add info about Flash to HTML decompilers and converters. Note that if the content developer put a password on the flash file, you may be SOL. the link provided will unlock certain passwords but not all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Flash extension called 'Swiffy' so you can export Flash content as HTML5. Later on you can make it SCORM compatible.

edit: up to 2MB if I'm not wrong.

Comment: ya u r right... but i have lots of flash content and now its not possible for me to convert them one by one.... i need such a tool which will convert the SCORM of that flash content into HTML5 content